# Why does the MAAS Proxy service keep dying when run in LXC?

Tags: maas, proxy

My MAAS controller keeps toggling back and forth between showing that the proxy service is working and has failed (and therefore it can not commission new machines):

[image: MAAS controller services]

Other details:

- This is MAAS 3.2 (installed via snap)
- I am running MAAS inside of an Ubuntu 20 LXD/LXC container.
- There are two physical interfaces (one is connected to the private BMC/IPMI network).
- I am using MAAS' built-in proxy service.

Questions:

- Is there a log I can look at somewhere to troubleshoot what the issue is with the MAAS proxy service?
- Anyone have any other MAAS proxy troubleshooting tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. Sort of. I still don't know where the MAAS Proxy system logs errors, so I don't know the exact reason that MAAS was dying, but I did find the solution.

The answer is simple. The LXC container needs to run in privileged/nested mode to support MAAS. This isn't the recommended way to run LXC for a public facing server, but if you're running in a secure environment, it's sometimes necessary.  So, here's the fix:

```
lxc stop {maas-container}
lxc config set {maas-container} security.privileged true 
lxc config set {maas-container} security.nesting true 
lxc start {maas-container}
```

This fix is applicable to LXD 3.03 and MAAS 3.2.